# Installing dvb-t Afatech AF9035?

Tags: dvb

Before I upgrade to ubuntu 11.10 I can Install it by this help :

http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/EzCap_DVB_T_Stick#Install_instructions_for_using_alternate_manufacturer_driver

But it doesn't work anymore ! 
First why ubuntu support it plug and play like other devices and like windows ?
Second How can I install it ?

I get this error :

```
1. Install ITEtech AF9035 Driver
2. Remove  ITEtech AF9035 Driver
Please Input Your Choise:
1
Please wait a minute
cp: cannot stat `api/.*.o.cmd': No such file or directory
make -C /lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/mahdiar/installer/AF903x_SRC modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/mahdiar/installer/AF903x_SRC/af903x-core.o
In file included from /home/mahdiar/installer/AF903x_SRC/af903x-core.c:1:0:
/home/mahdiar/installer/AF903x_SRC/af903x.h:15:21: fatal error: dvb-usb.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/home/mahdiar/installer/AF903x_SRC/af903x-core.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/mahdiar/installer/AF903x_SRC] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic'
make: *** [default] Error 2
make error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've successfully compiled it under 11.10, with some changes to the instructions on that [help page](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/EzCap_DVB_T_Stick). You should not have the device plugged in during this procedure (just in case...)

First type `uname -r` and note down the kernel version. In my case it is `3.0.0-13-generic`

Next, in the following line change it according to your kernel version, in my case it is:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-3.0.0-13-generic linux-source-3.00 kernel-package
```

Then, extract the kernel source to /usr/src with the following commands (once again change it to match your kernel version):

```
cd /usr/src
sudo tar jxvf /usr/src/linux-source-3.0.0.tar.bz2
```

Then just download the driver source to your home folder, extract it and create some symlinks to kernel headers (don't forget to change to your kernel version in the symlinks):

```
cd ~
wget http://me-tv.googlecode.com/files/AF903x.tar.gz
tar zxvf AF903x.tar.gz
cd installer/AF903x_SRC
ln -s /usr/src/linux-source-3.0.0/drivers/media/dvb/frontends/*.h .
ln -s /usr/src/linux-source-3.0.0/drivers/media/dvb/dvb-core/*.h .
ln -s /usr/src/linux-source-3.0.0/drivers/media/dvb/dvb-usb/*.h .
```

If you have kernel 3.0 you need to open two source files in a text editor and remove the `#include <linux/smp_lock.h>` lines (only one per file and almost at the top). The files are `~/installer/AF903x_SRC/src/af903x.h` and `~/installer/AF903x_SRC/api/usb2impl.c`.

Finally just run the installer and select the install option:

```
cd ..
sudo ./installer.sh
```

One last thing that you may need to do is to prevent the device from behing wrongly recognized as an USB HID (check the [help page](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/EzCap_DVB_T_Stick) for more info). So, just open `/etc/modprobe.d/usbhid.conf` and add the following:

```
options usbhid quirks=0x15a4:0x1001:0x0004
```

Then reboot the system or just reload the usbhid module with:

```
sudo modprobe -r usbhid
sudo modprobe usbhid
```

And that's it! For a quick test just use w_scan to see if it starts looking for frequencies. If it does not show an "NO USEABLE DVB-T CARD FOUND" error, the device should be working:

```
w_scan -L ~/channels.xspf
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer .But I have a problem after entering "sudo ./installer.sh" . I add the error to the main post .

Comment: Have you done the symlinking commands? The ones with "ln -s......"? You need to do it every time before compiling because the symlinks are cleared after a unsuccessful compilation.

Also try to do each of these commands twice (I've read that tip somewhere... don't know if it changes anything).

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It didn't work in my laptop but it works in my pc !!! maybe I should upgrade it to latest kernel !

Comment: One more question : Which software do you use for watching TV ?

Comment: For now I'm just using VLC. When I have some time I'll may look into a better alternative :) 
If it works don't forget to accept my answer

Comment: Hi I can't use your method any more . I got the error that is mentiond in the main post . (kernel 3.2) there is another solution in the linuxtv.org . I can't try it .

Comment: and it's unavailable for  kernel 3.5 !